# How to show a specific part of XML File?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm searching a way to show a specific part of code in a XML file.
I've a backup of SMS in xml file and I'm trying to code a software to show all messages from one contact (which is selected in a TextBox)
The big problem (for me) is that all informations (contact name, message,  phone number) are inside one tag.

Here is an example of xml file:

```
  <sms protocol="0" address="phone number" date="1338793176487" type="1" subject="null" body="SMS text" toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="phone number" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="null" readable_date="4 juin 2012 08:59:36" contact_name="contact name" />
```

PS: I'm using Visual Studio with .NET Framework

Comment: What is the attribute you want to search for? Contact name, phone number, ...?

Comment: I want to search the contact and after that every messages from the contact selected

Comment: Again, how does the contact identify itself? Do you want search for `contact_name="contact name"`. But there may be several people with the same name. Therefore `address="phone number"` seems to better identify the contact. Have you tried any of my proposed solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the attributes into a dictionary using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XElement sms = XElement.Parse(xml);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = sms.Attributes().GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[]` to specify conditions in XPath with [XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8) like this:

```
//sms[@address="..."]
```

This means: select all `sms` nodes with the condition that `@address` has the value `...`. The @-sign denotes an attribute.

Code example:

```
string xml = "<sms protocol=\"0\" address=\"phone number\" date=\"1338793176487\" type=\"1\" subject=\"null\" body=\"SMS text\" toa=\"null\" sc_toa=\"null\" service_center=\"phone number\" read=\"1\" status=\"-1\" locked=\"0\" date_sent=\"null\" readable_date=\"4 juin 2012 08:59:36\" contact_name=\"contact name\" />";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//sms[@address=\"phone number\"]");
foreach(var node in  nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to XML with an [XDocument](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=xdocument) and use a `where` clause to select nodes that have a particular attribute set.

Code example:

```
string xml = "<sms protocol=\"0\" address=\"phone number\" date=\"1338793176487\" type=\"1\" subject=\"null\" body=\"SMS text\" toa=\"null\" sc_toa=\"null\" service_center=\"phone number\" read=\"1\" status=\"-1\" locked=\"0\" date_sent=\"null\" readable_date=\"4 juin 2012 08:59:36\" contact_name=\"contact name\" />";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var nodes = from element in doc.Elements("sms") 
            where (string) element.Attribute("address") == "phone number"
            select element;
foreach(var node in  nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node);
}
```